# Error executing vim.schedule lua callback

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, lua, autocomplete, neovim

I want to be honest and brief, although I don't know English, I'm Venezuelan and I'm learning the language little by little (I hope you can understand me with the translation) I'm starting in web development. I am using ubuntu linux operating system (lubuntu), I have been configuring the Neovim code editor first, but I have an error with one of the plugins, the error is as follows:

```
Error executing vim.schedule lua callback: ...lugged/completion-nvim/lua/completion/signature_help.lua:18: attempt to index fie
ld 'resolved_capabilities' (a nil value)                                                                                       
stack traceback:                                                                                                               
        ...lugged/completion-nvim/lua/completion/signature_help.lua:18: in function 'autoOpenSignatureHelp'                    
        .../.vim/plugged/completion-nvim/lua/completion.lua:199: in function ''                                        
        vim/_editor.lua: in function <vim/_editor.lua:0>
```

That plugin is for code completion in javascript.

I hope a solution to not start from scratch please, I am a beginner and I really want to learn programming

Answer (score 3):

Judging from the error message, it seems you are following some obsolete blog posts on configuring neovim, since you are using [completion-nvim](https://github.com/nvim-lua/completion-nvim), which is already archived.

For auto-completion, the new norm is the following:

- Install [nvim-lspconfig](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig) (the helper plugin to help the users use the nvim builtin LSP) and the language server for your programming language
- Install [nvim-cmp](https://github.com/hrsh7th/nvim-cmp/) (the completion engine) and related plugins

If you are not familiar with all of this, you may try [lunarvim](https://www.lunarvim.org/) or [nvchad](https://nvchad.github.io/), which are the two most popular nvim pre-configs.